# Proof by contrapositive: Prove for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R},$ if $x$ is rational and $y$ is irrational then $x+y$ is irrational.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification

I read some answers on here, but I wanted some input on what happens if I try a proof and get a weird outcome.

I tried proving this by taking the contrapositive which is: if x+y is rational then $x$ is irrational or $y$ is rational

> Let $x+y=\frac{P}{Q}$ for some integers $P,Q$
> $$x = \frac{P}{Q} - y$$
> $$x = \frac{Py-PQ}{Q}$$
> (this shows that $x$ is actually rational - which contradicts my contrapositive statement?)

What does it mean when I find a contradiction when trying to prove the contrapositive statement? How should I proceed from here? Any tips would be appreciated $-$ I'm pretty new to proofs.

Comment: You use a proof by contradiction. You assume that $x$ is rational , $y$ is irrational and $x+y$ is rational. (Only in this case the conclusion would be false). But then $(x+y)-x=y$ as a difference of two rational numbers must be rational, the desired contradiction.

Comment: @Peter but why doesn't my contrapositive proof work out? If I find a contradiction while doing my contrapositive proof, wouldn't that make the statement false?

Comment: I don't think you showed that x is rational.

Comment: More precisely; why should $Py-PQ$ be an integer?

Comment: @Muselive you are right - there is no way to tell is that's an integer because of the Y. I didn't realize that.

Comment: The main reason I posted was to gain some knowledge as to how to know if my proof is valid or not - so maybe in this case I should've read my contrapositive statement of:  "if x+y is rational then  is irrational or y is rational" and realized that would be a burden to prove and perhaps to try a different route. The "or" seems messy to me. I don't know though - I'm very new to all of this? what do you think?

Comment: Assume $x+y$ is rational, the goal is to show that $x$ is irrational or $y$ is rational. This works as follows. If $x$ is irrational nothing has to be proven. If $x$ is rational, we can conclude that $y$ is rational. Hence the contrapostive can be proven as well.

Comment: Also note that "or" in logic allows that both statements are true, it is not an "either/or".

Comment: @Peter but wouldn't x being rational be a contradiction to the statement "x is irrational" when we made our contrapositive statement?

Comment: No, I split the proof into two cases $(1)$ "$x$ is irrational" $(2)$ "$x$ is rational". In both cases, the desired or-statement holds. So, it is proven because the exluding middle guarantees that we must have one of the cases. That $x+y$ is rational does not imply that $x$ is rational.

Comment: Would you mind typing this out as an answer? I'd like to better see/understand this proof in full using that logic - if not no worries

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113116/discussion-between-peter-and-isabelle-kreienbrink).

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to proof by contrapositive that for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R},$ if $x$ is rational and $y$ is irrational then $x+y$ is irrational.

The contrapositive of this statement is

> For all $x, y \in \mathbb{R},$ if $x+y$ is rational, then $x$ irrational or $y$ is rational.

Using logic notation, let $P,Q,R$ be statements, note that

$$P \to (Q \vee R) \iff (P \wedge \neg Q) \to R.$$

Hence to prove this statement, you can suppose $P$ and $\neg Q$, and derive $R.$ And you can do it using the proof by contradiction, you assume that $P$ and $\neg Q$ are true and $R$ is false and then derive a contradiction. This proves that $(P \wedge \neg Q) \to R$ is true, which is equal to the contrapositive we were ask to prove. Then we are done.

> *Proof*: Let $x, y \in \mathbb{R},$ such that $x+y$ and $x$ are rational. Suppose that $y$ is irrational. Let’s derive a contradiction. Since $x+y$ and $x$ are rational, then there are integers $a,b,c,d$ with $b \neq 0 \neq d$ such that $x+y=\frac{a}{b}$ and $x=\frac{c}{d}.$ Substituting $x$ in $x + y,$ we get
> $$\frac{c}{d}+y=\frac{a}{b}.$$
> Simplifying this expression, we get that $y=\frac{ad-bc}{bd},$ where $ad-bc$ and $bd$ are integers, with $bd \neq 0.$ Therefore $y$ is rational, which is a contradiction. Hence we prove that, if $x+y$ is rational, then $x$ irrational or $y$ is rational. By contrapositive, we conclude that if $x$ is rational and $y$ is irrational then $x+y$ is irrational. $\square$

Comment: Thanks for the tip - how should I know to choose a proof by contradiction over a proof by contrapositive? I want to learn more about what happens if I take a route in a proof (like I did in my original post) and get a strange outcome. Do I try a different method after that or should I have known prior to trying the contrapositive proof to do the contradictive proof?

Comment: Doing proofs in Mathematics is of major important. Let me suggest the reading of Chapters $1$ and $2$ of the book *Proofs and Fundamentals,* by Ethan D. Bloch. The first chapter give a brief informal treatment of logic (the necessary to construct proofs) and in chapter $2$ you will see several methods of doing proofs and will read a lot of well constructed proofs. Reading these two chapters will help you out understanding the methodology of doing proofs! Any help with the book just type here :)

Comment: To answer your question. It is hard to find what approach you should use to prove something. First, I encourage you to make some scratch work, trying different approaches, and when one results, you are ready to write the formal proof, if it fails, then try other method.

Comment: There’s is no simple rule to know in advance what type of proof you should make. But by practice (doing a lot of proofs) you will start to get a feeling, and even start to make some educated guesses. But you will only know when a method of proof works, when you are done with the proof

Comment: In this case, it is a lot easier to prove the contrapositive of our original statements. And in order to prove the contrapositive, we made use of a proof by contradiction. We combine several different approaches to prove one result

Comment: That's very interesting. My teacher didn't even mention combining the methods of proofs to get certain results - I'll keep that in mind moving forward!

Comment: Now you know you can do it, and that will help you in the future problems :)